# Force drop db while others may be connected

Tags: postgresql, maintenance

I need to remove a database from a PostgreSQL DB cluster. How can I do it even if there are active connections? I need sort of a `-force` flag, that will drop all connections and then the DB.

How can I implement it?

I'm using `dropdb` currently, but other tools are possible.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

**PostgreSQL 13** added:

```
DROP DATABASE mydb WITH (FORCE);
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html)

> `FORCE`
>
> Attempt to terminate all existing connections to the target database.
> It doesn't terminate if prepared transactions, active logical
> replication slots or subscriptions are present in the target database.
>
> This will fail if the current user has no permissions to terminate
> other connections. Required permissions are the same as with
> `pg_terminate_backend`, described in [Section 9.27.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL). This will
> also fail if we are not able to terminate connections.

---

In **PostgreSQL 12 and earlier**, you cannot drop a database while clients are connected to it.

At least, not with the [`dropdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-dropdb.html) utility - which is only a simple wrapper around [`DROP DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html) server query.

Quite robust workaround follows:

Connect to your server as *superuser*, using `psql` or other client. Do *not* use the database you want to drop.

```
psql -h localhost postgres postgres
```

Now using plain database client you can force drop database using three simple steps:

1. Make sure no one can connect to this database. You can use one of following methods (the second seems safer, but does not prevent connections from superusers).

   ```
   /* Method 1: update system catalog */
   UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'mydb';

   /* Method 2: use ALTER DATABASE. Superusers still can connect!
   ALTER DATABASE mydb CONNECTION LIMIT 0; */
   ```
2. Force disconnection of all clients connected to this database, using [`pg_terminate_backend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE).

   ```
    SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE datname = 'mydb';

    /* For old versions of PostgreSQL (up to 9.1), change pid to procpid:

    SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE datname = 'mydb'; */
   ```
3. Drop the database.

   ```
    DROP DATABASE mydb;
   ```

Step 1 requires *superuser* privileges for the 1st method, and *database owner* privileges for the 2nd one. Step 2 requires *superuser* privileges. Step 3 requires *database owner* privilege.

Comment: force be with you

Comment: It looks like a true killer feature!

Comment: just make sure every newbie like me know about that.   the (FORCE) or the "(" and  ")" is part for the  command.

Comment: Do you need to undo the `ALTER DATABASE mydb CONNECTION LIMIT 0;`? If so, how do you add back connections?

Comment: @brad-west no, because the database is deleted in last step and the setting is gone.

Answer (score 24):

**Postgres 13** adds the `FORCE` option for `DROP DATABASE`. See [filiprem's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11895/3684).

The shell utility [**`dropdb`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-dropdb.html) is basically just a wrapper around the SQL command and inherits the same option. So it's simple and reliable from the shell now, too:

```sh
dropdb mydb --force
```

Or short:

```sh
dropdb mydb -f
```

---

For **Postgres 12 and older**, there is a way with the shell utilities `dropdb` & `pg_ctl` (or `pg_ctlcluster` in Debian and derivates), too. But **[filiprem's method](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11895/3684) is superior** there for several reasons:

- It only disconnects users from the database in question.
- It does not need to restart the whole cluster.
- It prevents immediate reconnects, possibly spoiling the `dropdb` command.

I quote `man pg_ctlcluster`:

> With the `--force` option the "fast" mode is used which rolls back all active transactions, disconnects clients immediately and thus shuts down cleanly. If that does not work, shutdown is attempted again in "immediate" mode, which can leave the cluster in an inconsistent state and thus will lead to a recovery run at the next start. If this still does not help, the postmaster process is killed.  Exits with 0 on success, with 2 if the server is not running, and with 1 on other failure conditions. This mode should only be used when the machine is about to be shut down.

```sh
pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main restart --force
```

or

```sh
pg_ctl restart -D datadir -m fast
```

or

```sh
pg_ctl restart -D datadir -m immediate
```

immediately followed by:

```sh
dropdb mydb
```

Possibly in a script for immediate succession.

Comment: Not only is this less than ideal as it kicks the full postgres instance but it is not guaranteed to work. It is possible for a client to connect between the time you restart the server and attempt to run dropdb again. @filiprem 's answer above disables all connections to the database prior to disconnecting and will keep other databases up.

Answer (score 18):

Using @filiprem's answer in a my case and simplifying it:

```
-- Connecting to the current user localhost's postgres instance
psql

-- Making sure the database exists
SELECT * from pg_database where datname = 'my_database_name'

-- Disallow new connections
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'my_database_name';
ALTER DATABASE my_database_name CONNECTION LIMIT 1;

-- Terminate existing connections
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'my_database_name';

-- Drop database
DROP DATABASE my_database_name
```

Comment: on the UPDATE line it should be false not 'false'.

Answer (score 4):

For those finding this question now, 8 years later, PostgreSQL 13 finally adds the `--force` flag this question asks for:

`DROP DATABASE database_to_drop WITH (FORCE)`

or

`dropdb [-f/--force] database_to_drop`

will

> Attempt to terminate all existing connections to the target database. It doesn't terminate if prepared transactions, active logical replication slots or subscriptions are present in the target database.
>
> This will fail if the current user has no permissions to terminate other connections. Required permissions are the same as with pg_terminate_backend, described in Section 9.27.2. This will also fail if we are not able to terminate connections.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-dropdatabase.html

Answer (score 1):

Using [@Dorian's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163668/82844), fixed and enhanced:

```sh
DB="my_database_name" psql <<EOF
-- Making sure the database exists
SELECT * from pg_database where datname = '${DB}';

-- Disallow new connections
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = false WHERE datname = '${DB}';
ALTER DATABASE ${DB} CONNECTION LIMIT 1;

-- Terminate existing connections
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = '${DB}';

-- Drop database
DROP DATABASE ${DB};
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on something like RDS where connections without a database selected put you into the DB you asked to be created by default you can do this variant to get around yourself being the last open connection.

```
 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS temporary_db_that_shouldnt_exist; 

 CREATE DATABASE temporary_db_that_shouldnt_exist with OWNER your_user; 

 \connect temporary_db_that_shouldnt_exist 
 SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'the_db_you_want_removed'; 


 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS the_db_you_want_removed; 
 -- 
 -- Name: the_db_you_want_removed; Type: DATABASE; Schema: -; Owner: your_user 
 -- 

 CREATE DATABASE savings_champion WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'; 


 ALTER DATABASE the_db_you_want_removed OWNER TO your_user; 

 \connect the_db_you_want_removed 

 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS temporary_db_that_shouldnt_exist;
```

Comment: Small top to those that need to run this unattended: export DB='NAME'
sudo -E -u postgres psql <<EOF ...