# Dropped database still shows but causes errors PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

I had dropped a database a couple weeks ago but it still shows with `\l`.  I've tried using `DROP DATABASE mixmobi_master;` and the first time it gave me a confirmation message but `mixmobi_master` was still showing up with `\l`.  Now when I try that command again I get:

```
template1=# \l

template1=# drop database mixmobi_master;
ERROR:  database "mixmobi_master" does not exist

template1=# \l
                                 List of databases
      Name           | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
-------------------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
biterator_development   | kyle  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
mixmobi_master          | kyle  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
plantjotter_development | kyle  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
postgres                | atmos | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
template0               | atmos | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/atmos         +
                        |       |          |             |             | atmos=CTc/atmos
template1               | atmos | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/atmos         +
                        |       |          |             |             | atmos=CTc/atmos
(6 rows)
```

Every couple of minutes or so it will also give me this error message:

```
FATAL:  database "mixmobi_master" does not exist
DETAIL:  It seems to have just been dropped or renamed.
```

Anyone have suggestions?  I'm running Lion and had used Atmos' Cinderella environment.

---

### Edit

---

I used @Erwin's suggestion and got this:

```
template1=# SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = 'mixmobi_master';

datid |    datname     | numbackends | xact_commit | xact_rollback | blks_read | blks_hit | tup_returned | tup_fetched | tup_inserted | tup_updated | tup_deleted | conflicts |          stats_reset          
-------+----------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------------------
16387 | mixmobi_master |           0 |           9 |          2118 |       262 |     1826 |         2181 |        1157 |            0 |           0 |           0 |         0 | 2012-01-24 11:47:34.692079-06
(1 row)

template1=# SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
template1-# FROM   pg_stat_activity
template1-# WHERE  datname = 'mixmobi_master';
pg_terminate_backend 
----------------------
(0 rows)
```

Does anyone else have any suggestions?  I'm still getting these errors and nothing has worked so far!  Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3):

I would *guess* you had open connections / transactions while you dropped the db initially and the DROP is stalled somehow.

You can get more info on databases with [statistics views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE). For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database WHERE datname = 'mixmobi_master';
```

In case you find open backend processes, you might want to shut them down like this:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
FROM   pg_stat_activity
WHERE  datname = 'mixmobi_master';
```

More about that in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE).

Find a safe method to drop a database under load at this related answer:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected/11895#11895)

Comment: I used your suggestions but it didn't look like any backend processes were happening.  I posted the results in an edit to my question.

Comment: @JustLikeThat: Sorry this could not solve your problem. I am at a loss what the cause might be then.

Comment: Haha I know the feeling :/  Thanks for your time though!