# Adding nullable column to table costs more than 10 minutes

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.1, alter-table

I have problems to add a new column on a table.
I tried to run it a couple of times, but after more than 10 minutes running, I decided to cancel the query because of lock time.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn VARCHAR(50);
```

Useful information:

- PostgreSQL version: 9.1
- Number of rows: ~ 250K
- Number of columns: 38
- Number of nullable columns: 32
- Number of constraints: 5 (1 PK, 3 FK, 1 UNIQUE)
- Number of indexes: 1
- OS type: Debian Squeeze 64

I found [interesting information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmask-in-the-header/7383198#7383198) about the way PostgreSQL manages nullable columns (via HeapTupleHeader).

My first guess is that because this table already has 32 nullable columns with 8-bits `MAXALIGN`, HeapTupleHeader is 4 Bytes length (not verified, and I don't know how to do so).

So adding a new nullable column could need an update of HeapTupleHeader on every row to add a new 8-bits `MAXALIGN`, which could cause performance issues.

So I tried to alter one of the nullable columns (which is not really nullable in reality) in order to decrease to 31 the number of nullable columns, to check if my guess could be true.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER myothercolumn SET NOT NULL;
```

Unfortunately, this alter also takes very long time, more than 5 minutes, so I also aborted it.

Do you have an idea of what could cause this performance cost?

Comment: Well, I can tell you part of it: Altering a column type to another type that isn't binary compatible actually creates a new column, copies the data, and sets the old column as dropped. However, `SET NOT NULL` doesn't alter the type, it just adds a constraint - but the constraint must be *checked* against the table, and that requires a full table scan. 9.4 improves some of these cases by taking weaker locks, but it's still pretty heavyweight.

Comment: Before suspecting that it's performing slowly, you need to make sure that the ALTER TABLE is not just waiting for a lock. Mention it in the question if you have checked.

Comment: Thanks Craig and Daniel.

When I run the alter command, it appears in pg_stat_activity with waiting "true", I suppose that means it waits for a lock !?
It it the good way for checking ?
By the way, before running this alter, everything goes fine, but a few seconds after start, the number of locks grows up

Comment: Try the query at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_dependency_information for a better view. Either you have lingering transactions that forget to commit, or heavy activity with this table that keeps it always busy.

Comment: Might be a better fit at dba.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of misunderstandings here:

The **null bitmap** is *not* part of the heap tuple header. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-page-layout.html)

> There is a fixed-size header (occupying 23 bytes on most machines),
>   followed by an optional null bitmap ...

Your 32 nullable columns are unsuspicious for two reasons:

- The null bitmap is added **per row**, and only if there is **at least one actual `NULL` value** in the row. *Nullable* columns have no direct impact, only actual `NULL` values do. If the null bitmap is allocated, it's always allocated completely (all or nothing). The actual size of the null bitmap is **1 bit per column, rounded up to the next byte**. [Per current souce code:](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4cbe3abb3162d14a86bc8ec73fd9331638ec18a0/src/include/access/htup_details.h)

  ```
  #define BITMAPLEN(NATTS) (((int)(NATTS) + 7) / 8)
  ```
- The null bitmap is allocated after the heap tuple header and followed by an optional OID and then row data. The start of an OID or row data is indicated by `t_hoff` in the header. [Per comment source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4cbe3abb3162d14a86bc8ec73fd9331638ec18a0/src/include/access/htup_details.h):

  > Note that t_hoff must be a multiple of MAXALIGN.
- There is one free byte after the heap tuple header, which occupies 23 bytes. So the null bitmap for rows up to **8** columns effectively comes at no additional cost. With the 9th column in the table, [`t_hoff`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-page-layout.html#HEAPTUPLEHEADERDATA-TABLE) is advanced another `MAXALIGN` (typically 8) bytes to provide for another 64 columns. So the next border would be at **72** columns.

To display control information of a PostgreSQL database cluster (incl. `MAXALIGN`), example for a typical installation of Postgres 9.3 on a Debian machine:

```
    sudo /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_controldata /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
```

I updated [instructions in the related answer you quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmask-in-the-header/7383198#7383198).

All that aside, even if your `ALTER TABLE` statement triggers a whole table rewrite (which it probably does, changing a data type), 250K are really not that much and would be a matter of seconds on any halfway decent machine (unless rows are unusually big). **10 minutes or more indicate a completely different problem.** Your statement is waiting to get a lock on the table, most likely.

The growing number of entries in `pg_stat_activity` means more open transactions - indicates concurrent access on the table (most likely) that has to wait for the operation to finish.

#### A few shots in the dark

Check for possible table bloat, try a gentle `VACUUM mytable` or a more aggressive `VACUUM FULL mytable` - which might encounter the same concurrency issues, since this form also acquires an exclusive lock. You could try [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) instead ...

I would start by inspecting possible issues with indexes, triggers, foreign key or other constraints, especially those involving the column. Especially a corrupted index might be involved? Try `REINDEX TABLE mytable;` or `DROP` all of them and re-add them after `ALTER TABLE` **in the same transaction**.

Try running the command in the night or whenever there is not much load.

A brute-force method would be to stop access to the server, then try again:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected-in-postgresql/11895#11895)

Without being able to pin it down, upgrading to the current version or the upcoming 9.4 in particular *might* help. There have been several improvements for big tables and for locking details. But if there is something broken in your DB, you should probably figure that out first.

Comment: It's almost certainly locks. But, as a test, you can always create a copy of the table and try altering that. If that doesn't take very long then you know it's not the actual modification that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for explanations Erwin. I think you're right, it appears to be a lock problem.

When I check pg_stat_activity, I can see that my ALTER has a "waiting" true. 

What I can't figure out is why the ALTER can't get the lock on the table, cause even when I can't find any query running, it appears it can't get it.
But as soon as my ALTER begins to run, all other queries are waiting for it to finish.

So, the activity seems to indicate that the ALTER locks all other queries, but also indicates that ALTER did not get the lock.

I think there is something I don't understand well !?

Comment: @MatthieuVerrecchia: Did you try the test Richard suggested?

Comment: I just cloned my table to a new one (with pg_dump -> pg_sql).
The new column is correctly added in 50ms, which confirms the lock problem.
By the way, still don't understand why ALTER can't get lock with really standard db activity.

Comment: @MatthieuVerrecchia : basically because (some) ddl-statements are special.

Comment: @MatthieuVerrecchia: I added a few shots in the dark

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've followed your suggests and tried a VACUUM, then a REINDEX.
The REINDEX was also blocking, cause it was also unable to acquire lock .. After some investigations, the problem was more simple than we thougth .. There were a one-week remaining <IDLE> with an opened transaction
The problem is solved, thanks for everything, informations were very useful.