# Extremely slow query on indexed column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, index-tuning, amazon-rds, order-by

I'm getting a extremely slow query on an indexed column. Given the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE shop_id = 3828 
ORDER BY updated_at desc 
LIMIT 1
```

`explain analyze` returned:

```
    QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..594.45 rows=1 width=175) (actual time=202106.830..202106.831 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using index_orders_on_updated_at on orders  (cost=0.43..267901.54 rows=451 width=175) (actual time=202106.827..202106.827 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (shop_id = 3828)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1604818
 Planning time: 98.579 ms
 Execution time: 202127.514 ms
(6 rows)
```

The table description is:

```
                                         Table "public.orders"
       Column       |            Type             |                           Modifiers
--------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass)
 sent               | boolean                     | default false
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone |
 name               | character varying(255)      |
 shop_id            | integer                     |
 recovered_at       | timestamp without time zone |
 total_price        | double precision            |
Indexes:
    "orders_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_orders_on_recovered_at" btree (recovered_at)
    "index_orders_on_shop_id" btree (shop_id)
    "index_orders_on__updated_at" btree (updated_at)
```

It's a Postgres server, running on an AWS RDS t2 micro instance.
The table has around 2.6 million rows.

Comment: Does it stay the same after doing an `ANALYZE orders;`?

Comment: No, it's still extremely slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know Postgresql too well, but you're checking across two seperate keys to find the values you're looking for, try creating it as a composite key instead

```
"index_orders_on_shop_id" btree (shop_id)
"index_orders_on__updated_at" btree (updated_at)
```

becomes

```
"index_orders_on_shop_id__updated_at" btree (shop_id,updated_at)
```

that could help

if there's a way to include values in an index that would work even better

Comment: This is probably the best solution. The reason seems to be that optimizer thinks it can find the right `shop_id` soon when going in `updated_at` order, reason may be bad statistics or just skewed data (statistics are not good at showing skewness), so it does not use the right index (as it can pick only one and the ordering seems more important at that moment).

Answer (score 8):

There is a subtle problem hidden in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

Would sort NULL values *first*. I assume you do not want that. Your column `updated_at` can be NULL (lacks a [`NOT NULL` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#id-1.5.4.6.6)). The missing constraint should probably be added. Your query should be fixed either way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   orders 
WHERE  shop_id = 3828 
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1;
```

The multicolumn index [@Ste Bov mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112812/3684) should be adapted accordingly:

```
CREATE INDEX orders_shop_id_updated_at_idx ON orders (shop_id, updated_at DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Then you get a basic `Index Scan` instead of the (almost as fast) `Index Scan Backward`, and you won't get an additional `index condition: Index Cond: (updated_at IS NOT NULL)`.

Related:

- [Unused index in range of dates query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90128/unused-index-in-range-of-dates-query/90183#90183)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

#### Asides

You can save a bit of wasted disk space by optimizing the sequence of columns for your big table (which makes everything a bit faster):

```
id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval( ...
shop_id            | integer                     |
sent               | boolean                     | default false
name               | varchar(255)                |
total_price        | double precision            |
recovered_at       | timestamp without time zone |
created_at         | timestamp without time zone |
updated_at         | timestamp without time zone |
```

See:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Add `NOT NULL` constraints to all columns that cannot be NULL.

Consider [`text` or `varchar` instead of `varchar(255)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560486/939860), [`timestamptz` instead of `timestamp`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107481/3684) and [`integer` for the price (as Cents)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81450/different-kinds-of-pricing-postgresql/81550#81550) or `numeric` (for fractional numbers) which is an [arbitrary precision type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) and stores your values *exactly* as given. ***Never*** use a [lossy floating point type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) for a "price" or anything to do with money.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is: you do use index but the number of rows returned and should be sorted is too big to fit into your instance type memory. So you can create index on shop_id + updated_at columns as btree index is always sorted. Unfortunately in your case the shop_id isn't selective enough so in addition to that the hash partition on shop_id might be useful.