# Can subqueries decrease the data fetching times?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
Order
id: Serial
date: timestamp
item: varchar(255)
user_id: UNSIGNED INT References to users
```

```
Users:
id: UNSIGNED INT
email: varchar(255)
type: ENUM(CUSTOMER,ADMIN)
```

And I want to fetch for a whole year of 2022 the customer orders:

```
select 
  orders.id,
  orders.item,
  orders.date,
  customer.name,
from
  orders join users on orders.user_id = users.user_id
where
  users.type = 'CUSTOMER' and date_part('year',orders.date) = 2022
```

But an alternate approach is to use subqueries:

```
select 
  orders1.id,
  orders1.item,
  orders1.date,
  customer.name,
from
  (select * from orders where date_part('year',order.date) = 2022) as orders1
  join (select * from users where users.type = 'CUSTOMER') as customers 
  on orders1.user_id = customers.user_id
```

But when is recomended the first approach and when is recomended the second one? What I want to achieve is faster data retrieval from the database upon the internet. Does table size is a parameter that I need to consider as well when I write select queries?

Comment: I would be very surprised if there is any noticeable difference between the two queries. I am quite sure, both will result in exactly the same [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: If there is an index on `date`, using `where order.date >= date '2022-01-01' and orders.date < date '2023-01-01'` (instead of date_part) will be more efficient

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries can help performance when they lead to a different query plan. (Like, if you aggregate in a subquery before you join ...)
That's not the case for the query you show. The second form is just a noisy, convoluted equivalent of the first - which can be optimized a bit:

```
SELECT o.id, o.item, o.date, c.name
FROM   orders o
JOIN   users  u USING (user_id)
WHERE  u.type = 'CUSTOMER'
AND    o.date >= '2022-01-01'
AND    o.date <  '2023-01-01';
```

Like a_horse commented, the rewritten filter expression is potentially *much* faster if it can be use an index on `(date)` (unlike your original, which is not "sargable"). It will be even faster without involving an index.

The literal *'2022-01-01'* happens to be a valid `date` or `timestamp` alike. The time part is assumed to be `00:00` if missing. It even works for `timestamptz` (but introduces a corner-case dependency on the time zone setting of the current session.) I did not add an explicit type cast so it is coerced to the matching type with an assignment cast.

#### Aside

Your table definition of *"Order"* gives me the twitches.

Mixed case spelling is ambiguous. Did you double-quote the name to preserve that unfortunate name? [`ORDER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) is a reserved word, don't use it as identifier. (Seems to be a typo, and the table name is `orders` after all.)

`id: Serial` - consider an `IDENTITY` column. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)

`date: timestamp` - don't name a `timestamp` column "date". That's just misleading. Best don't use basic type names as identifier at all.

`item: varchar(255)` - this particular size limit type is typically a misunderstanding in Postgres. See:

- [Do fixed-width rows improve PostgreSQL read performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113149/do-fixed-width-rows-improve-postgresql-read-performance/113162#113162)

`user_id: UNSIGNED INT` - Postgres `integer` type is signed (as is `smallint` and `bigint`), you would have to install the [additional module `pguint`](https://github.com/petere/pguint), which I would *not* advise. See:

- [How to store one-byte integer in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159090/how-to-store-one-byte-integer-in-postgresql/159916#159916)