# Select only last row from table for list of values

Tags: postgresql, performance, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

As example we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   a BYTEA NOT NULL,
   r_pointer BIGINT,
   s_pointer BIGINT,
   data BYTEA,
   PRIMARY KEY(a, r_pointer)
) PARTITION BY HASH (a);
```

In case we I want get last element:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE a ='\xaaa' order by r_pointer desc limit 1;
```

Of course, I can use `executemany` for this statement, but this is not very good for performance.

How can I get only the first row found for each element in a given array like `{\xaaa,\xbbbb}`. Similar to the following, but this returns all rows:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE  a = ANY ('{\xaaa,\xbbbb}'::bytea[]) 
ORDER  BY r_pointer DESC;
```

Comment: "Of course I can use executemany for this statement, but this is not very good for performance"  Have you tried it?  Please show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) for it.

Comment: `executemany` is not Postgres terminology. Are you thinking of MySQL? Or something like psycopg? Please also clarify: Postgres version, how many input values (min/max/avg), cardinality of `t1`, what to return exactly when no matching row is found for one / all input values. The best course of action depends on these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For big tables, modern PostgreSQL (your example suggests Postgres 11, since PKs are not supported for partitioned tables before that), and many input values, this should perform excellently:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   unnest('{\xaaa,\xbbbb}'::bytea[]) a
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  t1.a = a.a
   ORDER  BY t1.r_pointer DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) t1;
```

Your PK on `(a, r_pointer)` provides just the index needed for this.

Related:

- [How to properly implement compound greatest-n filtering](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114407/how-to-properly-implement-compound-greatest-n-filtering/114413#114413)