# Adding partial unique index very slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I attempted to create a partial unique index for a table like example 11-3 [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tests (
    subject text,
    target text,
    success boolean,
    ...
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tests_success_constraint ON tests (subject, target)
    WHERE success;
```

However, (to mimic creating the index in a production environment) I additionally used the `CONCURRENTLY` keyword, so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY tests_success_constraint ON tests (subject, target)
    WHERE success;
```

If course, I understand, [according to this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY), that creating an index concurrently takes "*significantly longer to complete*", however, in my test environment on a table with **~20K rows** and no other users of that table, this command has now run for **an hour and is still going at it** and I feel that this is a bit too much (especially when looking forward to applying the command in production where there is traffic on that table).

Of course, the table contains some more columns than the example and a `UNIQUE` constraint against (the equivalents of) `(subject, target)` but it does not look like anything that should hinder the creation of a new index that much.

I see that [there has been a fellow sufferer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102509/speed-up-creation-of-postgres-partial-index) but as that case is with a huge table compared to mine, I tend to think that his problem is not applicable to me.

The only thing that I think is relevant is that the `success` column in my case currently consists of mostly NULLs, only a few rows that contain TRUE there. Would that be the thing that makes that much of a difference?
Or any other hidden caveats that I may have stumbled on?

Comment: Indexing 20k rows should only take seconds. My guess is that your `create index` is waiting for a lock: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: Correct, another app is holding an AccessShareLock on the whole table. However, considering that the app only does read-only accesses to the table I would have thought that the index creation would get its slot of time to do its thing, no? Or do I really have to cut out every user of the table before starting to generate the index ("CONCURRENTLY")?

Comment: An `AccessShareLock` is a regular lock that is acquired when reading from a table. That should not block a `create index concurrently`. Is your `create index` actually _waiting_ for another session?

Comment: IIRC `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` still needs to get a moderately strong lock, just briefly. So a long running lock could still prevent it from getting started.

Comment: @CraigRinger _'PostgreSQL supports building indexes without locking out writes. This method is invoked by specifying the CONCURRENTLY option of CREATE INDEX. When this option is used, PostgreSQL must perform two scans of the table, and in addition it must wait for all existing transactions that could potentially use the index to terminate.'_ http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY

Comment: @dezso Confirmed with a quick test and a code check, `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` is not blocked by `ACCESS SHARE` lock. It takes a `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` lock, which conflicts with its self and stronger locks. A stuck `VACUUM` could cause issues, but not much else that doesn't also block updates. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: @Manjabes Check `pg_locks`. Also look at `pg_stat_activity` for the command. Is it marked `waiting`? What's your exact PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @CraigRinger I was also thinking it can be blocked by a lock - but the 'could potentially use the index' is quite broad.  For example, if the index could be used to identify the row to get a lock on it falls into this case.  Furthermore, in a quick test, all indexes on the table to read from get an `AccessShareLock`, too.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, in my case there was another app that had a bug where it started a transaction but did not commit nor roll it back. When that app was fixed, the index creation succeeded even when it had an AccessShareLock .