# Creating index on TIMESTAMP column to use with range operators

Tags: postgresql, index, timestamp, range-types

**TLDR**: Can I create an index that's used by the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE foo_date <@ tsrange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')
```

---

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    foo_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    foo_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (foo_id)
);
```

This table contains 100,000 records with dates from `2009-01-01` to `2018-12-29`. I'd like to be able to query for rows in a given date range (e.g. for rows in January 2018).

## Option 1

One approach is to use the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31';
```

The problem of this approach is that if `foo_date` occurred on `2018-01-31` after midnight, they wouldn't be included in this query. So I could change the query to `BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'`. The problem *then*, however, is records that occur on `2018-02-01 00:00:00`. These would be included, which I don't want.

## Option 2

Another option, put forth by [Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), is to use this construct:

```
foo_date >= '2018-01-01' AND foo_date < '2018-02-01'
```

(Yes, this blog is for SQL Server, but seems to be applicable here).

While this form unequivocally gives me the results I want, it's cumbersome: I have to repeat the column name twice.

## Option 3

Since Postgres gives us the range data type, I thought a clearer form might be:

```
foo_date <@ tsrange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')
```

So my next question is, if I use this form, can I use an index to speed up operation?

---

With Options 1 and 2 above, a normal b-tree index can be used:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_foo ON foo(foo_date);
```

A query using Options 1 or 2 will use the index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo 
WHERE 
    foo_date >= '2018-01-01' 
    AND foo_date < '2018-02-01';
```

gives me this query plan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=21.95..592.70 rows=942 width=12)
  Recheck Cond: ((foo_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (foo_date < '2018-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_foo  (cost=0.00..21.71 rows=942 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((foo_date >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (foo_date < '2018-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

However, if I use Option 3, the index isn't used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo 
WHERE foo_date <@ tsrange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01');
```

gives me:

```
Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..1791.00 rows=500 width=12)
  Filter: (foo_date <@ '["2018-01-01 00:00:00","2018-02-01 00:00:00")'::tsrange)
```

If I try to create a gist index, I initially get an error message.

```
ERROR:  data type timestamp without time zone has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
SQL state: 42704
```

After adding the `btree_gist` extension, I can create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_foo ON foo USING gist (foo_date)
```

However, using the `@>` or `<@` still doesn't make use of the index.

Is there something I'm missing? Or is it just not feasible to create an index that can be used by this construct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name *"foo_date"* indicates a `date` and is a bad choice for a `timestamp` column. **Option 1** would work just fine with actual *dates*.

A plain btree index in combination with **Option 2** *is* the unequivocally best solution. Look no further. Except maybe for the special case of a BRIN index for large tables with physically sorted data. See:

- [Speed up creation of Postgres partial index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102509/speed-up-creation-of-postgres-partial-index/102513#102513)

#### Proof of concept

That said, to make a GiST or SP-GiST index work, you could create an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on fake ranges. You do not need the module `btree_gist` for this. Demonstrating with SP-GiST since that is typically a bit faster here. See:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111524/939860)

```
CREATE INDEX foo_date_spgist_idx ON foo USING spgist(tsrange(foo_date, foo_date, '[]'));

SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE  tsrange(foo_date, foo_date, '[]') <@ tsrange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')
```

Or with range literal:

```
...
WHERE  tsrange(foo_date, foo_date, '[]') <@ '[2018-01-01,2018-02-01)'
```

**But:** bigger, more expensive to maintain, slower than the btree index. Not even less cumbersome to write. Pointless for your case.

Aside: *technically*, you could:

```
... WHERE foo_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31 23:59.999999';
```

The Postgres timestamp type is (currently) implemented with µs resolution, i.e. max. 6 fractional digits. Hence the expression does exactly what you want. But I strongly advice against building on this implementation detail. Option 2 is the way to go. Related:

- [Interval (days) in PostgreSQL with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31127978/939860)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: Excellent! I hadn't thought of indexing a "dummy" range (although I agree this isn't the way to go, not least because you end up still having to type the column name twice). It seems a shame that there's not a better way to use an index for Postgres's range operators this way, but I suppose it's best to stick with the SQL standard in these cases. I agree about the name `foo_date`. This was a quick mock-up, and it was the name that came to me. Thank you!'