# Time Series Table ( Many Columns ) Design Recommendations

Tags: postgresql, database-design, design-pattern

I am storing Time Series Data in a Postgresql database.

I am wondering what the performance ramifications are of the following two proposed design patterns.

Option 1:
    A single table with a timestamp and many columns ( maybe 100 ) containing various measurement data.

```
TABLE measurement (id, timestamp, measurementA, measurementB, measurementC ...)
```

Option 2:

Two tables. One with an id and timestamp and another table which contains a reference to the measurement table and then multiple fields describing the recorded data.

```
TABLE measurement (id, timestamp)
TABLE measurement_data (id, measurement_id, description, type, value)
```

I like the idea of option two. As my table structure is much smaller and simpler. However I have concerns of the effects of queries on the table. Will there be a huge performance hit for a simple query such as the following?

Using Option 1s Design

```
SELECT measurementA 
FROM measurement 
WHERE timestamp > X AND timestamp < Y
```

Using Option 2s Design

```
SELECT value 
FROM measurement_data 
WHERE description = 'measurementA' 
  AND measurement_id IS IN (SELECT id 
                            FROM measurement 
                            WHERE timestamp > X AND timestamp < Y )
```

Comment: Please consider also checking other related questions that show in the right-hand side column on the page. https://imgur.com/a/U2yop04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`type` of option 2 is not represented in option 1. Makes the comparison slightly unfair, but hardly matters.)

The major difference between the two options is **storage size**. Assuming datatype `real` for your measurements and `bigint` for IDs (for lack of info), the row size of **option 1** is:

8 + 8 + 100 x 4 + 24 + 4 = **444 bytes**.

While the same occupies with **option 2**:

8 + 8 + 24 + 4 = 44 bytes in table `measurement`. Plus ...
(8 + 8 + 13 + 4 + 4 + 24 + 4) x 100 = 6500 bytes in `measurement_data`.
So **6544 bytes (!) total** in option 2 for one row in option 1.

Plus you need more indexes in option 2, half of which are bigger by the same factor than in option 1 as well. Seems hopeless. Size matters.

OTOH the query for option 2 retrieves only rows with 65 bytes per hit in `measurement_data`, but it adds the overhead of at least an additional index-only scan on `measurement`. Still might prevail for a large number of hits and clustered (more considerations!) data. And updates should be cheaper, producing less table bloat - but such a design typically does not see many updates. Many related considerations depending on the complete picture.

**In any case, ditch option 2** which stores some attributes redundantly over and over. Consider **option 3** instead, a classical m:n relationship:

```
TABLE measurement (measurement_id bigint PK, ts timestamp)
TABLE measurement_kind (measurement_kind_id int PK, type int?, description text)
TABLE measurement_data (measurement_id bigint, measurement_kind_id int, value real, PK (measurement_id, measurement_kind_id))
```

Still 44 bytes for `measurement`. Plus:
(8 + 4 + 4 + 24 + 4) * 100 = **4400 bytes** in `measurement_data`
So **4444 bytes total** in option 3 for one row in option 1.

(And a negligible 100 x (4 + 4 + 13 + 3 + 24 + 4) = 5200 bytes *once* --> 8k mini-table for `measurement_kind`.)

The equivalent query to go with it:

```
SELECT md.value 
FROM   measurement m
CROSS  JOIN (
   SELECT measurement_kind_id
   FROM   measurement_kind
   WHERE  description = 'measurementA'
   ) mk
JOIN   measurement_data md USING (measurement_id, measurement_kind_id)
WHERE  m.ts > X
AND    m.ts < Y;
```

**Resumé: Maybe option 1, maybe option 3, never option 2.**

Related (suggested!):

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Thanks very much @Erwin Brandstetter really appreciate your input. Your OPTION 3 sounds like a better version of my approach for OPTION 2. I really like that. I will mark this answer as complete and correct. In some respects I know this is an OPINION question/ circumstance question however I think you laid out the implication of the various approaches and even better, provided a more appropriate option. Thanks very much!

Comment: The value attribute on the measurement_data table. In some circumstances we store varchar and booleans. Would it be reasonable to store this data all as varchar and use the measurement_kind to cast to the relevant type on an application level? And again we now open another line of discussion of the implications of having to cast every object pulled from the database on the application.

Comment: There is the additional cast, there's also additional storage and more error opportunities for data not stored as the naturally fitting type. In the "option 3" model, you might have separate tables for boolean or character data. Or have multiple columns with different types in one table and only *one* column can be filled. [NULL storage is cheap.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91849/3684) It all depends on the complete use case.

Comment: Thanks again @Erwin Brandstetter I will review this again. More discussion with the Engineers makes it appear that we may have to go with option 3.