# How do I select by a JSONB array containing at least one element within a range?

Tags: postgresql

I need to model products with properties.  Properties need to be dynamic, in the sense that application users can add / delete properties to products.  For this reason, I am using a JSONB column storing a JSONB object to model those dynamic properties, with each field of the object a dynamic property, for instance:

```
{
  product_number: "snsug1",
  color: "white",
  weight: [100, 200, 300]
  ...
}
```

Furthermore, as can be seen in the example above, some properties are allowed to have multiple values, as some products can come in different configurations (different values for the *weight* property for instance, for packets of sugar of different sizes).  I am modeling those as JSONB arrays.

I need to be able to select products based on some filter values for the properties.

Filtering based on comparisons on single value properties are straightforward (for instance `where properties->'color' = '"white"'::jsonb`) and overlap queries for multi-value properties are straightforward too when the overlap target contains discreet values, like `where properties->'weight' @> any(array[to_jsonb(200), to_jsonb(300)])`.

The problem comes with filtering on a multi-value property based on overlap with a range of values (instead of overlap with discreet values as above).  So my question is:  how can I filter on a multi-value property like *weight*, with criteria that any of the values in the array should fall with a range?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
select id from products where properties->'weight' @> range(50, 150);
```

should return the entry in my example above, but

```
select id from products where properties->'weight' @> range(350, 500);
```

should not.

The `weight @> range(50, 150)` bit in the pseudo code query above is what I am asking about.  What should that look like?

If I am barking up the wrong tree altogether and this is not doable with my current model, then what would be a good alternative for solving my problem?  Is there a more appropriate way of modeling the data that can lead to elegant and fast queries of the type above?  The solution needs to perform well on large data sets, it needs to be able to make use of indexes for the above types of queries.

Comment: I currently have data in EAV structure and trying to migrate away from it because of difficulty with querying it.  The structure is just `(property_definition_id uuid, product_number text, value jsonb)`, but for multi-values, there can be multiple tuples with the same `property_definition_id` and `product_number`.  Perhaps I'll play with the current EAV implementation a bit more to see if it's workable after all, but so far it's proven hard to query.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a sub-query that unnests all array elements together with an EXISTS predicate:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(p.properties->'weight') as t(weight)
              where t.weight::int <@ range(50, 150));
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, this appears to work beautifully!

Comment: @yakutori If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If this is dynamic, how do you know that weight exists and is an array of int in the first place, in order to write the query?

There is (strangely) no function or operator to convert a JSONB array to a PostgreSQL array, you need a helper function to do that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.jsonb_to_intarray(jsonb)
 RETURNS int[]
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
select array_agg(x::int) from
   (select jsonb_array_elements($1)) as f(x);
$function$
```

Once that is in place, you can use the ANY feature of PostgreSQL:

```
select id from products where 
    int4range(50, 150) @> any(jsonb_to_intarray(properties->'weight'));
```

Comment: thanks yes good question and solution.  Perhaps I'll try that as well and compare with @a_horse_with_no_name's solution above, that I tried and works very well.  To answer your question:  the user can define new properties that live in their own table and have a data type and whether they are single or multi value as part of their definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you chose to operate with a Postgres array, use an efficient conversion function with an ARRAY constructor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.jsonb_arr2int_arr(_js jsonb)
  RETURNS int[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text($1)::int)';
```

(Assuming all values are indeed `integer`.)

See:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

But you can operate on the nested JSON array in the `jsonb` column directly, too. The `ANY` construct also accepts a *set*. See:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860)

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM   products
WHERE  int4range(50, 150) @> ANY ((SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(properties->'weight')::int));
```

Either way, if keys like *'weight'* are only present in relatively small subsets of all rows, the query can profit from index support. While I don't see an easy way to employ an index for the range containment itself, a default jsonb_ops GIN index should be instrumental to identify rows with a 'weight' property to begin with:

```
CREATE INDEX products_properties_idx ON products USING GIN (properties);

SELECT *
FROM   products
WHERE  int4range(50, 150) @> ANY ((SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(properties->'weight')::int))
AND    properties ? 'weight';  --  logically redundant, to get idx support
```

If, on the other hand, *'weight'* is present in most rows or even just 20 % or so, consider adding a dedicated *column* to your table instead. NULL storage is very cheap. This would then be cleaner, more efficient and easier to query.

Comment: Thanks @erwin-brandstetter - useful answer.  Some properties will be limited to relatively few products, but others will definitely have an occurence of >20%, so those could do with their own columns, but the original problems still applies, which is that properties need to be user-definable.  Would it perhaps be feasible to trigger `ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN ...` statements on `INSERT` on the property definitions table, or would that not be good practice?  I can imagine problems with cascading view changes and functions referencing those views.

Comment: @yakutori: `ALTER TABLE` in a trigger would be madness. Which attributes to put in dedicated columns is hard to tell without knowing the complete use case. There are many things to consider. Typically, advantages of dedicated columns are underestimated in my experience. NULL storage is *very* cheap. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91849/3684 et al. The `jsonb` column can serve as catch-all for not (yet) established and common attributes.