# PostgreSQL Drop Database With Connected Users

Tags: postgresql

I've searched and tried a lot, but I can't figure out a proper solution to dropping all connections so I can properly drop a database.

[Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected?newreg=e08f921389494984b4d2a4063255f385)

This topic from 2012 discusses that we should first stop allowing connections to the database. If I execute the command in step 1 I can no longer run commands.

```
psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' where datname = 'postgres';"
psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend (pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'postgres';"
dropdb -h localhost -U postgres postgres
```

The result of all commands after the first is:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "postgres" is not currently accepting connections
```

Once I'm at this point I have no idea how to recover other than stopping postgresql, deleting the database folder and recreating the database using initdb.

[PostgreSQL DROP DATABASE](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-drop-database/)

This tutorial doesn't include anything on disallowing connections. So I run the following:

```
psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -c "SELECT pg_terminate_backend (pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'postgres';"
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
connection to server was lost
dropdb -h localhost -U postgres postgres
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "postgres" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 6 other sessions using the database.
```

I've also tried revoking access like so, but this doesn't stop PGAdmin III from connecting so I assume I messed up the command.

```
psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -c "REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE postgres FROM public;"
```

I'm not sure how to continue. I see a lot of topics on this issue, but nothing works. Note, I'm running these commands in a shell script, but if I run them from the CLI I get the same results.

Comment: Once you've set `datallowconn = 'false'`, it does exactly what it says on the tin, and doesn't allow connections to that database. Have you tried connecting as the `postgres` user to `template1` instead of the `postgres` database to drop the `postgres` database?

Comment: @Kassandry - That works perfectly. I knew about template0, but by default template0 doesn't allow connections. Did not know template1 existed. I am now able to do exactly what I require. Thank you! If you submit this as a answer I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Postgres 13 (to be release in Q4/2020) will have an option to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've set `datallowconn = 'false'`, it does exactly what it says on the tin, and doesn't allow connections to that database.

Connecting as the `postgres` user to the `template1` database should allow you to drop that database.

For more information check the documentation on [template databases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html). They're quite useful. =)