# Can not drop a PostgreSQL database using dropdb?

Tags: postgresql, linux, maintenance

I can not drop a database using

```
dropdb
```

I get this error:

```
 ERROR:  must be owner of database
```

but with `psql \l` I see user admin (the one dropping the db) with

```
 admin=CTc/postgres
```

besides the database I want to drop.

What is wrong in PostgreSQL 9.x in Linux?

Comment: BTW, version 9.x does not make sense for Postgres since major version numbers *include* the first number after the dot - before the upcoming version 10 where this changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see there with `psql \l` only means that the Postgres role `admin` has been granted a couple of privileges by the Postgres role `postgres` - which is the default superuser and probably the actual *owner* of the database.

[Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)

> If a superuser chooses to issue a `GRANT` or `REVOKE` command, the command
> is performed as though it were issued by the owner of the affected
> object. In particular, privileges granted via such a command will
> appear to have been granted by the object owner.

[The privileges granted are](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html):

```
C -- CREATE
c -- CONNECT
T -- TEMPORARY
```

`CONNECT` and `TEMPORARY`on databases are also default default privileges for `PUBLIC`, but what we see here has been granted explicitly.

The privilege to drop the DB is not given, it cannot be. Only the owner of the database can drop it. (Or a superuser.) Hence the error message:

> ERROR:  must be owner of database

Typically, each shell user connects with a Postgres role of the same name. So, given you have the necessary `sudo` rights, this should do it:

```
sudo -u postgres dropdb my_database_name_here
```

Or switch to the shell user `postgres` like demonstrated here:

- [PostgreSQL error: Fatal: role "username" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11919677/939860)

But you may have to disconnect other users first. See:

- [Force drop db while others may be connected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected/11916)